# The icons and their meanings in BizTalk Admin console

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Is there a description of various icons we see next to the items in BizTalk Server Administration console?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on ServerFault - but the MSDN documentation should be your main source here...